# Detecting mouse is moving in upward ,left ,right or downward direction in js/jq

Tags: javascript, jquery, geometry

I am creating a geometric campass tool using svg, in which there are 3 btns ,
1) for moving the whole campass which is in the center
2) for increasing the radius of the circle
3) for rotating the radius of the circle
4) for drawing the circle using path(svg) on the basis of position of 4th btn which is always be on the the circle circumference.

So I have a function,

`updateCircle(cx,cy,r,angle)`
`in this function it is finding the position of all 4btns and the radius of the circle (which is line in svg) and the radius and center of big circle`

[image: Circle]
For more info,
Here c1 to c5 are circles and l1 is a line in svg
[image: circle 2]

For first btn ,I am updating the circle position with the current cursor moving point on the mousedown,mousemove and then mouseup on the first btn.

By default the value of angle is 90deg.

So for 2nd btn in which I have to increase radius on the basis of mouse is moving in downward direction and decreasing radius in case of mouse is moving in upward direction when it radius is in 3rd and 4th quadrant and do opposite when radius is in 1st and 2nd quadrant.

So Here comes question :-

**How I can able to detect mouse is moving in upward and downward direction?**

Or is there any way that I can do the operation of increasing and decreasing radius by performing any mousedown and mouse up event on the second btn?

And second question is :-

**How I can create the functionality of third btn (as I am sure I have to do something with angle but a little bit confused , like when the radius is in 3rd ,4th quadrant and mouse is moving towards left the increasing angle and when mouse is moving towards right decreasing angle and vice versa when the radius is in 1st and 2nd quadrant)**

Any suggestions should be appreciated and valuable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Detecting mousemove direction**

You can easily determine whether the mouse is moving up or down by keeping a reference to the previous mouse position, comparing it with the new one, then updating the previous mouse positions with the current for the next iteration. Here's an example of how that can be accmplished in JavaScript:

```js
const lastPoint = {x: null, y: null}
window.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  const leftOrRight = (
    e.clientX > lastPoint.x ? 'right'
    : e.clientX < lastPoint.x ? 'left'
    : 'none'
  )
  const upOrDown = (
    e.clientY > lastPoint.y ? 'down'
    : e.clientY < lastPoint.y ? 'up'
    : 'none'
  )

  /* 
    here you can apply the transformations you need to, 
    then update the cursor position tracker for the 
    next iteration
  */

  lastPoint.x = e.clientX
  lastPoint.y = e.clientY
})
```

**Rotation**

Assuming you're using CSS transformations, you can track a rotation variable in the javascript and dynamically apply it to the DOM element's inline CSS. Using the same method as above, you can rotate one way when they are moving the mouse up, and the other way when the are moving down. Here's how that can be accomplished.

circle.html

```html
<div class="circle" style="transform: rotate(0deg);"><div class="inner"></div></div>
```

circle.css

```css
.circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.circle .inner {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: orange;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

rotate.js

```js
const rotatingCircle = document.getElementsByClassName('circle')[0]

const lastPoint = {x: null, y: null}
let rotation = 0
window.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  rotation += (
    e.clientY > lastPoint.y ? -1
    : e.clientY < lastPoint.y ? 1
    : 0
  )

  rotatingCircle.style = `transform: rotate(${rotation}deg);`

  lastPoint.x = e.clientX
  lastPoint.y = e.clientY
})
```

See live rotating example here: https://codepen.io/OneCent/pen/jOEMpEr

Let me know if this helps or if you have any questions!

Comment: This makes my answer obsolete. Very clean.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have a few questions as,
1) when we are detecting mouse direction , suppose user is moving in left, downward direction then in case of points like (100,100),(99,99)..(1,1) is also supposed to be trigger as down or if moving like (1,1),(2,2)..(100,100) then trigger as upward but it will return none. So how can I deal with this?

2) I have to start this calculation when a user mousedown on the 2btn and then m
try to move in direction (i.e, mousemove) here so how can I deal with it?

Comment: In short, my first question was, how I can deal with diaognally direction (left downward/upward,right downward/upward ?

Comment: @AyushSrivastava (1) I think an assumption of yours is incorrect. While moving diagonally, humans don't do so in a perfectly straight line. There may be some cases in the trip from (100, 100) to (1,1) where there was no vertical movement, in that case a 'none' string would be returned. If you get a 'none', ignore it and use the direction value from the previous iteration. If you want to dynamically determine the direction angle at which they are moving the cursor, that solution would require a bit more complexity than my answer.

Comment: @AyushSrivastava (2) assign the function I attached to the window to a variable name. Attach it to the window only after the button is clicked. When you want to stop listening for user input, remove it from the window using the same variable name reference. You can read more about how event listeners work here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Answer (score 0):

To determine whether the mouse is moving up or down you just have to track the y-coordinate of the position of the mouse. I'd use y1 (representing previous position) and y2 (representing new position) variables to track the position/movement. Look up Mouse Event clientY and mousemove event to help you.

For the third button, you should look up "rotation about a point" and/or "rotate segment about a fixed point." If your algebra is ok the math is doable.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just want to  check in which direction user moved the mouse after a mouse down click event and I used below code snippet to achieve the same

```
let y_down,y_up;
document.addEventListener("mousedown", function(event) {
console.log("statrt",event)
y_down=event.screenY
});

document.addEventListener("mouseup", function(event) {
console.log("end",event)
y_up=event.screenY
// console.log(y_down - y_up) 
if(y_down - y_up > 0){
 console.log("mouse moved up");
}else
{
console.log("mouse moved down");
}

});
```